# Changing clothes in Kochi

Tags: india, clothing, kerala, laundry

I am thinking of volunteering in Kochi, Kerala, India and it all looks good except for one thing: doing laundry by hand. I absolutely HATE this. I would like to minimize doing this so based on the temperature in Kochi around February how long is it possible to go without changing clothes except briefs and still avoid being stinky? I will be spending all my time in the city, not trekking around.

Comment: This is a funny question! :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, about changing clothes in Kerala, to stay fresh and hygienic you will need to do it twice in a day to be frank. Once after taking bath, and once may be before going to bed. So there is no way you could not get stinky without changing clothes after every bath.

Doing laundry by hand is not such a bad thing. Maybe this is the time when you can learn doing it and save yourself from unnecessary botheration for the coming years of your life!

That being said, if you want to completely avoid it you have few other options too.

First, if you have the time and money then you could find a laundromat and they will do it happily for you at some cost. Here is a list of few launderers in Kochi.

http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/dry-cleaners-laundry-services_cochin

Secondly, if there is a domestic help around your facility where you are going to live you could politely ask him/her if they wish to do it for you. If they need the money they will happily accept the part time job for as less as Rs. 50 per bucket maybe. You might feel that you are making somebody work for you, but they will be more than happy since that small amount of money means a lot for them.

Comment: +1 on the "hire someone to do it."  I paid my maid in Nepal about $3/week (1998) to cook for me, clean for me, and do my laundry. I offered her a raise - she refused, because she didn't want the stress of earning more than her peers.  As a westerner, it probably feels weird - but this is precisely the first step in becoming immersed in a foreign culture.

Answer (score 2):

It will be really hot and sticky so clothes won't last  for long.  I used to wash my clothes whilst having a shower to kill two birds with one stone.  Then they dry really quickly as it is so hot. There will be loads of places doing laundry though.

Comment: shower scrub huh? not a bad idea. i'll keep it in mind. however, can anyone post links to self service laundromats in kochi if they exist? they're prolly cheaper